# import VueJS Components from a json file

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

We are having here a funny project / issue (it's about Joomla! who's interested in). However, in main.js I want to import a json file like:

`import componentSetting from './plugin.components.json'`

where `plugin.components.json` simply looks like

```
{
  "Devices": "./components/settings/devices.vue"
}
```

Now, I want to import this there defined components dynamically, for instance:

```
for(let name in componentSetting){
    import(componentSetting[name])
    // or
    Vue.component(name, import(componentSetting[name]));
}
```

This idea fails. Components can not be found, or path is wrong and so on. 
I also rewrote my loop with Promises, because `import` returns a Promise, but this doesn't work either. Is this idea completely nonesense, or does there exist a solution.

Thanks,
Allan

Comment: You'll need to read the JSON file before you can get values out of it (it doesn't export variables like a JS file). Use the built-in `fs` module to read the file, `JSON.parse()` to parse the data and then use it like `import componentSetting from parsedJSON.devices;` where `parsedJSON` is the parsed data that you read from the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem on a previous project, and solved it importing the json file and using `Object.entries` to iterate over the keys.

The javascript file:

```
import componentsJSON from './components.json'; 

Object.entries(componentsJSON).forEach( item => {
    Vue.component( item[1].basename, require(`${item[1].path}`).default  );
});
```

The json file:

```
{
   "Instagram": {
        "basename": "instagram", 
        "path": "./core/components/Instagram0501.vue", 
        "props": {
            "user-id": "1111",
            "access-token": "111",
            "limit": 5
        }
    },  
    "FeaturedProducts0501": {
        "basename": "featured-products-0501", 
        "path": "./core/components/products/FeaturedProducts0501.vue", 
        "options": []
    }
}
```

Also, I created a component that renders all the components included in that json file:

```
<template>
   <div class="home" >

    <component v-for="(component, index) in json" 
               :key="'component'+index" 
               :is="component[1].basename" 
               v-bind="component[1].props">
    </component>

  </div>
</template>
<script>

    import componentsJSON from '../components.json'; 

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                json: Object.entries(componentsJSON)
            }
       }
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks you two, I will test this in a few day, now I am working on other project, but I will answer / comment / mark / vote it then.